# Replace 1 character from the link

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Google has an old link:

```
http://example.com/blog/?top-name-electronics-at-great-prices
```

And i need old link to work and redirect to:

```
http://example.com/blog/top-name-electronics-at-great-prices
```

I know it supposed to be easy but tried so many things and only getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule **as your very first rule** in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /$0%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

However, **if there is already a .htaccess inside `blog/`** then use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^/?$ /blog/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes it worked, but for some reason i get an extra '/',

Comment: And /blog/?query   turns into this:
/blog//query

Comment: '/blog/?query'  becomes '/blog//query'

i need it to be without second slash